# TensorFlow TFRecords read one specific image

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, protocol-buffers

I want to load only one image from the TFRecords file which I've created with [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py), and with a directory structure of:

```
├── train
|   ├── chef
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data5467.png
|   ├── chicken
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data2098.png
|   ├── parasaurolophus
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data2977.png
|   └── Trex
|       ├── data0.png
|       ├── ...
|       └── data2841.png
├── validation
|   ├── ...
├── build_image_data.py
└── labels.txt
```

Resulting in a single file: `train-00000-of-00001` containing all the images from above (124MB Binary).

Now I want to read in the first image from the TFRecords file, which should be the `train/chef/data0.png`. How do I do that?

How do I read in a single specific image from my custom dataset at test time, when all images are stored in the same TFRecords file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question.
You need a pipeline to parse the tfrecords file, it should go like this:

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([you_tfrecords_file_name])
_, serialized = reader.read(queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialied, features={you_features_dict})
image = features[your_image_name]
image.set_shape(you_image_shape)
```

after this, you can run your image out as a np.ndarray type with

```
sess.run(image)
```

each time you call this line code, one image will be dequeued in the order in which they were written into the tfrecords file

second question, when you convert all images into tfrecords, its hard to do vaildation with queues as inputs, I personlly recommend you to convert training image to `train.tfrecords` and valid images to `valid.tfrecords` and use sharing variables to get two logits for those two inputs, for details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187764/tensorflow-efficient-feeding-of-eval-train-data-using-queue-runners/40287999#40287999)