# How TensorFlow connect operator to placeholder without sess.run?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I'm new to tensorflow .
I'm trying to connect pool5 layer output to my model

Pretrained model:

```
with open("vggface16.tfmodel", mode='rb') as f:
  fileContent = f.read()

graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(fileContent)
x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32,32,3],name="raw_images_mh")
x_tf_1=tf.image.resize_images(x_tf,224,224)
y_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None,],name="turth_y_mh")
feature_x=tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='vggface', input_map={ "images": x_tf_1 },return_elements=["pool5:0"])
```

My model:

```
newsaver=tf.train.import_meta_graph('PretensorWhimh.ckpt.meta')
newsaver.restore(sess,'PretensorWhimh.ckpt')
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
pool5=graph.get_tensor_by_name("feature_x:0")
results=graph.get_tensor_by_name("fintune_whimh/measure/predict/ArgMax:0")
```

I can use twice run to get the result:

```
pool_x=sess.run(feature_x, feed_dict={x_tf:frames[arr[:10]]})[0]
sess.run(results, feed_dict={pool5:pool_x}
```

But how to connect they together?(from vgg to finetune)
i.e. feature_x to pool5
[image]

Comment: You can not change inputs of an op after it's been created. However, you could modify the string giving input of your `pool5` feature in the .pbtxt file to the name of your feature_x tensor

Comment: thank you for mention that!  
I use the following ways to solve it, freeze my own graph and import it (or it will be not initialized)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748552/tensorflow-how-to-replace-a-node-in-a-calculation-graph