# Optimize a graph built by two imported graphs Tensorflow

Tags: python, optimization, graph, tensorflow, placeholder

I need to use the output from a graph as the input to another one for a deep learning project, and then optimize all the variables of the two graphs. The input of each graph is a placeholder.

My problem is very similar to the one discussed here: [Tensorflow: How to replace a node in a calculation graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748552/tensorflow-how-to-replace-a-node-in-a-calculation-graph)

Unfortunately, the question was not resolved due to an error that I am getting as well as pointed out at that time. I'll post my case

This is a sample program which actually do trivial computations

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_1:
    input_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3,3], name="input")
    weight1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3], stddev=0.1), name="weight")
    y = tf.matmul(input_1,weight1)
    # NOTE: using identity to get a known name for the output tensor.
    output1 = tf.identity(y, name="output")

gdef_1 = g_1.as_graph_def()

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_2:  # NOTE: g_2 not g_1       
    input_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3,3], name="input")
    weight2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3], stddev=0.1), name="weight")
    z = tf.matmul(input_2, weight2)
    output2 = tf.identity(z, name="output")

gdef_2 = g_2.as_graph_def()
```

Then I import the two graphs in another graph:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g_combined:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3,3], name="input_matrix")

    # Import gdef_1, which performs f(x).
    # "input:0" and "output:0" are the names of tensors in gdef_1.
    y, = tf.import_graph_def(gdef_1, input_map={"input:0": x},
                           return_elements=["output:0"])

    # Import gdef_2, which performs g(y)
    z, = tf.import_graph_def(gdef_2, input_map={"input:0": y},
                           return_elements=["output:0"])

    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(z-x))
    variables = [op.outputs[0] for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if op.type == "Variable"]
    print (variables)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost,var_list = variables)
```

This is the solution suggested in the previously linked question, but it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Argument is not a tf.Variable: Tensor("import/weight:0", dtype=float32_ref)
```

The variable `variables` contains:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'import/weight:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Tensor 'import_1/weight:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32_ref>]
```

Does anyone know how to make it work? Or how to optimize the entire structure, considering that I need an intermediate result to feed a placeholder?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you use the exact same code suggested in the previously linked question, are you able to reproduce the result? If so, then you can compare between your version and the working version to help identify the cause of the error?

Comment: I said that I get the same result as in the previous link, whose version does not work (exactly as mine).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is not to replace the graph but to initially build a graph which contains all nodes from the union of the graphs you want, and subgraphs to train the independent and joint models. Then by saving and loading individual variables you should be able to jointly optimize things.