# Internally feeding to an intermediate tensorflow placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

After loading a pre-trained neural net from disk `tf.saved_model.loader.load` I have a session that I can run and feed data to. Eg:

```
with sess.graph.as_default():
    input_var = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
    out_var = graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0")
    print sess.run(out_var, feed_dict={input_var: some_data})
```

However I need to tell tensorflow to do some pre-processing, eg add some noise and then normalize the input tensors. Is there a way to feed an intermediate tensor to the `input` tensor without passing control to python, ie. calling `eval`/`run` only once? Effectively I want to compose the loaded graph *after* another graph.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585310/add-low-layers-in-a-tensorflow-model

Comment: Yes that's exactly it thank you!