# How to add a new layer to an existing TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm loading a `protobuf` file of an already trained model and want to add a `custom op` on the input- as well as on the output-layer. Is this somehow feasible or is the design freezed once it is trained and exported?

Unfortunately I could only find options to initially (i.e. before export) redesign the model.

Comment: With god's help I've found an option on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770771/3085931